# Using the # symbol in Pascal to type characters past 127 range

Tags: character-encoding, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I know that in pascal you can use the `#` character to display certain characters like **tab**(`#9`), **carriage return line feed**(`#13#10`), ect.
 When I try to do other characters out of the 127 range like `#169` it replaces it with a question mark.
 How do I change the character encoding in lazarus so I can use this character?

Comment: Windows: Properties of the console box?  If Linux, change the encoding of your console/terminal program

Comment: It doesn't *replace it* anywhere. It might *display it* differently. How are you displaying the text where you're seeing the `?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Free Pascal:

> The `#` indicates the control string
>
> The control string can be used to specify characters which cannot be typed on a keyboard, such as #27 for the escape character.

See [free pascal character strings](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse8.html).

The above page also mentions:

> **It is possible to use other character sets in strings:** in that case the codepage of the source file must be specified with the `{$CODEPAGE XXX}` directive or with the -Fc command line option for the compiler. In that case the characters in a string will be interpreted as characters from the specified codepage.

For example, If you wanted to encode with UTF-8 you could use ([see this page](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu87.html)):

```
{$CODEPAGE UTF8}
{$Mode ObjFPC}{$H+}
```

(If you are on windows you can choose from [these code pages.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

I tested the following example on my mac with the fpc (free pascal compiler):

```
program Example;
{$CODEPAGE utf8}
{$Mode ObjFPC}{$H+}
Begin
   writeln('Hello World'#13#10);
   writeln('carriage return line');
   writeln('Example: '#$C3#$A4);
End.
```

This example prints out the `ä` character and is a modification of the examples on the [dealing with UTF8 in free pascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Better_Unicode_Support_in_Lazarus#Dealing_with_UTF8_strings_and_characters_in_code) page, which will help you a lot with this issue. You may have to adjust the solutions on that page to fit your problem.

Note, that I was able to access the `ä` character because I used it's hex value `C3A4`.